# How do I overwrite the user's IP in Expressjs in Node.js

Tags: node.js, session, express, proxy, cloudflare

How do I change the recognized IP address by express sessions?

I'm using cloudflare, so the x-forwarded-for header is set.

I need to be able to set the session for the client IP.

Answer (score 1):

Express has a `trust proxy` [application setting](http://expressjs.com/4x/api.html#app-settings) that allows checking of `X-Forwarded-*` header values. Set it to whatever value makes sense for your configuration, just beware that setting the config value to `true` picks the left-most value in the chain, which can easily be spoofed.

Comment: I'm not exactly trying to do that.  I may need to rephrase my question